# how to store selected value of a dropdown as a id in mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, insert, dropdown

I am getting data from a builders table and show it in a drop down list here is the code.

```
<select style="width:154px;">
      <?php 

        include('connection.php');
        $show_builder = "SELECT * FROM builders";
        $result_builder = mysqli_query($conn,$show_builder);
        while($data_builder = mysqli_fetch_array($result_builder)){

            echo"<option>".$data_builder['builder_name']."</option>";
        }
        ?>
```

I want to select a value and store it as an `id` in the user's table as a `builder_id` in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
    include('connection.php');
    $show_builder = "SELECT * FROM builders";
    $result_builder = mysqli_query($conn,$show_builder);
    echo '<select name="builder">';
    while($data_builder = mysqli_fetch_array($result_builder)){

        echo'<option value="'.$data_builder['id'].'" >'.$data_builder['builder_name'].'</option>';
    }
    echo "</select>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In short you must have `name` attr of the `select` and to add `builder_id` as `value` attr of `option` tags:

```
<select name="builder_id" style="width:154px;">
    <?php
        include('connection.php');
        $show_builder = "SELECT * FROM builders";
        $result_builder = mysqli_query($conn, $show_builder);
        while ($data_builder = mysqli_fetch_array($result_builder)) {
            echo '<option value="'.$data_builder['builder_id'].'">' . $data_builder['builder_name'] . '</option>';
        }
    ?>
</select>
```